# How to introduce 'noise' to an N-Ball boundaries while keeping it balanced?

Tags: probability, euclidean-geometry, geometric-probability

Given an N-dimensional space and a set of randomly distributed points in it, I define an N-Ball and I classify as "1" all points within the N-Ball, and "0" for all the rest.

I'm looking for a way to introduce 'noise' into this boundary, but only in some dimensions. What I naively implemented, is taking one of the points and before assigning it class 1 or 0, add a gaussian noise (with mean 0) to some of its cartesian coordinates, and then calculate the point's "noisy" modulus to figure out if it should be "1" or "0"

However, this approach unbalances the classes, as there are more offset values that would 'throw' the point outside the N-ball than those that would throw it inside. This unbalance gets worse if the noise (variance of the gaussian noise) increases, and/or if the dimensions increase.

I tried also capping the maximum amount of offset I add to the point's coordinate, to that coordinate's absolute value. The effect is reduced, but it's still there.

So, given all this, what would be the "balanced" way to introduce noise to coordinates so that the ratio of "1" vs "0" is maintained (on average?)

Answer (score 0):

You can scale your points to unbalance them.

If they’re Gaussian before and you add Gaussian noise, then you can just scale by the prior variance divided by the sum of the prior variance and the noise’s variance. This will preserve the distribution.

Otherwise, if you are capping or your points weren’t initially Gaussian, it’s nontrivial/impossible to preserve the distribution after adding noise. If you could repeatedly generate scenarios, then you could determine by simulation how much to scale to keep the relevant statistic the same.

Comment: The points initial distribution is uniform along cartesian coordinates. I thought of simulating and then scaling the noise amplitude to preserve the ratio, but since this would depend on the 2 adjustable parameters (dimensions and ratio), I figured maybe there's a more elegant solution to this than testing multiple 2-tuples of parameters and adjusting.

Comment: Oh, in that case there are very nice solutions. First, since the coordinates are independent, you can treat them separately as long as you preserve the distribution. 

If you use uniform noise to a uniformly distributed variable, the resulting distribution will look like a trapezoid. You can calculate the cdf of this and then scale it, effectively squeezing the sides of the trapezoid and scaling it. Do this to each dimension separately.